# Получение фрагмента

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment, adapter, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager, в адаптере получаю два фрагмента и возвращаю их

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return listWords.getInstance();
        case 1:
            return AddWord.getInstance();
    }

    return null;
}
```

А это уже код самого фрагмента

```
public class AddWord extends Fragment
{
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.add_word;

private View view;

public static AddWord getInstance()
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    AddWord fragment = new AddWord();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containers, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, containers, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

и в основном активити к View Pager уже присваиваю адаптер

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Так вот как мне получить фрагмент в основном активити чтоб можно было управлять текстом итд уже через основное активити

Comment: так делать не правильно. Fragment доожен сам управлять своим *текстом и т. д.*. Кроме того, вы каждый раз создаете новый инстанс фрагментов в адаптере вместо того, чтобы использовать их повторно. Для двух фрагментов это не имеет значения, но если их будет больше - это приведет к падению производительности.

Comment: У меня в первом фрагменте находиться лист а во втором кнопки и поля для добавления, и если каждый фрагмент будет управлять своими элементами то как я добавлю элемент с поля в лист ?

Answer (score 1):

Fragment получать так :

```
Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragmentTag");
```

Comment: Только как бы фрагмент надо брать из ViewPager, а там не тегов не йд нету...